# ExpressionChanged error but no lifecycle hooks

Tags: javascript, angular, lifecycle

I'm trying to access a couple of material drawers so I can open/close them in another component, however I am getting the following error:

> `NavigationComponent.html:30 ERROR Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'sideNavsDrawers: undefined'. Current value: 'sideNavsDrawers: [object Object],[object Object]'.`

I have read that this is normally a product of putting inappropriate functionality into lifecycle hooks, however I have just started this app and have zero lifecycle hooks.

I have a navigation component that I'm attempting to pass a `QueryList` of `MatSideNav`s to.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-navigation',
  templateUrl: './navigation.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./navigation.component.scss']
})
export class NavigationComponent {
  @ViewChildren(MatSidenav) sideNavsDrawers: QueryList<MatSidenav> | undefined;
}
```

Within its template I have

```
<app-toolbar [sideNavsDrawers]="sideNavsDrawers"></app-toolbar>
```

And within that component

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-toolbar',
  templateUrl: './toolbar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./toolbar.component.scss']
})
export class ToolbarComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() sideNavsDrawers: QueryList<MatSidenav> | undefined;
}
```

Adding the union for `undefined` was something I added when I saw the previous value was `undefined` in the error, but I don't know if it is necessary.

#### Why are these very simple components generating this error, and how can I eliminate it?

## [Reproduced on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cj4zer)

Comment: This link might help https://indepth.dev/everything-you-need-to-know-about-the-expressionchangedafterithasbeencheckederror-error/

Answer (score 1):

The exception is triggered when a value used for data binding changes as the view is being updated, which is the case for the `QueryList` populated with `ViewChildren` in `NavigationComponent`.

You can avoid the exception this way:

1. Redefine the `sideNavsDrawers` input property as an array:

```
export class ToolbarComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() sideNavsDrawers: Array<MatSidenav>;
}
```

2. Construct the array with the template reference variables instead of using `ViewChildren`:

```
<mat-sidenav #leftDrawer ... >
...
<mat-sidenav #rightDrawer ... >
...
<app-toolbar [sideNavsDrawers]="[leftDrawer, rightDrawer]">
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3yddbn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fnavigation.component.ts) for a demo.

Comment: Yes, I found this workaround as well. I still find it a bit irritating that I can't pass down a query list. Thanks very much.